# Facing the errors on listing tensor my Pnft

Tags: solana-program, rust, nft

I'm encountering issues with the enforcement of royalties on Tensor when minting programmable NFTs from different wallets. When minting the PNFT from one wallet, the royalty is fixed and verified. However, when minting from another wallet and listing it on Tensor, one account shows the royalties as optional while the other shows them as enforced. The problem persists even though you minted them at the same time.